# How to keep a cookie value when user visit other pages?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to maintain a cookie that is set to not to disappear when a user visit other pages. The situation in my code is that it gets a parameter of the page location and saves it into the `/` path.

Here's my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    try {
        var url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        // Get gclid,token or fbclid parameters
        var gclid = url.searchParams.get("gclid");
        var token = url.searchParams.get("token");
        var fbclid = url.searchParams.get("fbclid");

        // token expires in 6 hours
        document.cookie = `gclid=${gclid}; max-age=21600` + ";path=/";
        document.cookie = `token=${token}; max-age=21600` + ";path=/";
        document.cookie = `fbclid=${fbclid}; max-age=21600` + ";path=/";

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Issues with Parsing URL Parameter's - " + err);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
www.test.com/contact?gclid=123   // saves the cookie value
```

When going to other pages `www.test.com/about` it also sets a value to null because the cookie is coming from the url parameters.

the `gclid=123` is stored in a cookie in the path `/`. But when I go to other pages like `wwww.test.com/about`

the `gclid` cookie will be equal/set to `null`.

The situation here in my code is that everytime the user visits a pages the `url.searchParams` searches for the desired parameter and if it does found those parameter the cookie will be sit to `null`.

How do I keep the previous value of the cookie `gclid` if the new `gclid` contains a `null` value in my page? And updates the `gclid` if it does not contains a `null` value.

Comment: do you mean to keep the previous value of `gclid` if the new `gclid` is `null` on the new page?

Comment: @lastr2d2 yes I want to keep the previous value of the `gclid` and if `gclid` detects another parameter which is `!= null` it updates the cookie.

Comment: will it work if you put the `document.cookie = xxx` statements inside a `if` check ? `if(gclid !== null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check if the parameter is exist

```
window.onload = function () {
  try {
    var url_string = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    ['gclid', 'token', 'fbclid'].forEach(function (key) {
      var value = url.searchParams.get(key);
      if (value) {
        document.cookie = `${key}=${value}; max-age=21600` + ';path=/';
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Issues with Parsing URL Parameter's - " + err);
  }
};
```